# How would I programmatically select a font with the Fontselect jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, prototype

I'm using the Fontselect jQuery plugin, and it is working great, but I'd like to select a font from the drop down programmatically anytime I want in my code. It looks like it's using a prototype function, but I can't seem to get access to to it correctly and call it's functions.

The plugin is located here: https://github.com/tommoor/fontselect-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no method in order to select a font from the plugin a way to solve it is based on simulating the click and mouse events...

```js
function selectFontAndApplyToEle(fontName, callback) {
    $('div.font-select').find('.fs-results li').removeClass('active');
    var dropEle = $('div.font-select').find('.fs-drop');
    var fontToSelect = $('div.font-select').find('.fs-results li:contains(' + fontName + ')');
    dropEle.addClass('fs-drop-op');
    var posFont = fontToSelect.offset().top
    var posFontOffset = $('div.font-select').find('.fs-results li:first').offset().top
    $('div.font-select').find('.fs-results').scrollTop(posFont - posFontOffset);
    fontToSelect.addClass('active').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('div.font-select a div').trigger('click');
        dropEle.removeClass('fs-drop-op');
        callback && callback(fontToSelect.data('value').replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }, 500);
}

$(function () {
    //
    // Init the fontselect plugin
    //
    $('input.fonts').fontselect({
        style: 'font-select',
        placeholder: 'Select a font',
        lookahead: 2
    }).on('change', function(e) {
        var fontFamily = $(this).val().replace(/\+/g, ' ');
        $('p').css('font-family', fontFamily);
    });


    selectFontAndApplyToEle('Anton', function(fontFamily) {
        $('p').css('font-family', fontFamily);
        setTimeout(function() {
          selectFontAndApplyToEle('Anonymous Pro', function(fontFamily) {
              $('p').css('font-family', fontFamily);
          });
       }, 1000);
    });
});
```

```css
.fs-drop-op {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/tommoor/fontselect-jquery-plugin/master/fontselect.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tommoor/fontselect-jquery-plugin/master/jquery.fontselect.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="fonts">

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
    in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
    passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
    PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

An alternative way to achieve your goal can be:

```js
function setFontToEle(ele, fontname) {
    //
    // select the font by name in fontselect plugin list
    //
    var font = $('div.font-select').find('.fs-results li:contains(' + fontname + ')').data('value');
    if (font === undefined) {
        return;
    }
    //
    // include the css if not yet included
    //
    var link = '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' + font;
    if ($("link[href*='" + font + "']").length === 0){
        $('link:last').after('<link href="' + link + '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
    }
    //
    // apply the font to the element
    //
    ele.css('font-family', font.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

$(function () {

    //
    // Init the fontselect plugin
    //
    $('input.fonts').fontselect({
        style: 'font-select',
        placeholder: 'Select a font',
        lookahead: 2
    });

    //
    // hide the font select if not necessary
    //
    $('.font-select').hide();


    //
    // set font to element
    //
    setFontToEle($('p'), 'Anton');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/tommoor/fontselect-jquery-plugin/master/fontselect.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tommoor/fontselect-jquery-plugin/master/jquery.fontselect.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="fonts">

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
    in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
    passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
    PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that looks like how to choose a font in a certain element, but I would like to select a font from the Fontselect plugin dropdown without clicking it. Say if I click a text box with text written in a certain font, the font name would show up in that drop down automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Is the alternative solution supposed to actually change the font in the drop down? The solution almost works, but it is giving me problems with click events.

Comment: Don't call which function? I found a way not to call the click function which I used to set text to the selected font by setting a boolean and then setting the bool back to false when the setTimeOut is finished. Anyway the selectFont function is causing problems with not displaying the correct font. I can see multiple are selected, and the correct name does not show up as the selected item.

Comment: @VagueExplanation Answer updated. I added a callback function and a demo with two consecutive font changing. Lat me know

Comment: That's way more clunky than I would want it to be, but it's working! Though strangely it's complaining that the callback is not a function "TypeError: callback is not a function. (In 'callback(fontToSelect.data('value').replace(/\+/g, ' '))', 'callback' is undefined)" and jQuery is complaining once "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.nodeName.toLowerCase')"

Comment: I'm guessing the callback isn't always meant to pass? I put if(callback) before calling it, and it got rid of the error. The jQuery error still persists.

Comment: @VagueExplanation Snippet updated. You can change the callback call in: callback && callback(fontToSelect.data('value').replace(/\+/g, ' '));  in order to avoid undefined. This happens when the parameter is not passed.

Comment: That's a cool way of doing it. Do you know what the jQuery error could be about?

Comment: Somehow I got rid of it